# updating elasticsearch-oss package 6.8 to 7.17

Tags: elasticsearch, debian, elasticsearch-6.8

i have elasticsearch-oss 6.8 installed. What is the difference with elasticsearch-oss and elasticsearch packages? How can i update elasticsearch-oss 6.8 package to 7.1?

I can't find anything about "oss" on official documantation page.

```
elasticsearch-oss/stable,now 6.8.23 all [installed]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can upgrade from 6.8 to 7.X following the [upgrade docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/setup-upgrade.html)

as of 7.10 Elasticsearch no longer has an OSS package available due to [license changes](https://www.elastic.co/blog/license-change-clarification), and instead just ships a default distribution that contains free and open code and features